# Translation verification for a notice

Tags: translation, cantonese, traditional-characters, writing

Hello everyone I hope you can help me with a translation. I am looking for a Cantonese teacher (or speaker for that matter) in my area and I want to post a notice. I have asked and received a translation on a different site but I would really appreciate a second opinion.

> Cantonese Teacher Wanted!
>
> I am learning Cantonese and I would really need a teacher. I am
>   willing to pay. If you know Cantonese and are willing and able to
>   teach please contact me. Basic level of English or Romanian required.
>   If you need help with either of these two languages I can help you as
>   well. Phone Number : xxx...; E-mail : xxx...;
>
> 聘用廣東話教師
>
> 本人正在學習廣東話並且需要一位教師。若果你對廣東話有一定的認識以及懂得教學的話，敬請聯絡本人。
>   本人願意付學費。要求教師有基本英文或羅馬尼亞語的智識。若果閣下希望在這兩種語言得到幫助，本人也可以提供幫助。 本人聯絡電話:xxx...;
>   本人聯絡電郵:xxx...;

Comment: `若果` -> `如果`, `智識` -> `知識`.

Comment: 英文或羅馬尼亞語 --> use both with 文 or both with 語.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help! I thought I should post the final version of the notice here. Cheers

聘用廣東話教師
本人正在學習廣東話並且需要一位教師。如果你對廣東話有一定的認識以及懂得教學的話，敬請聯絡本人。
本人願意付學費。要求教師有基本英文或羅馬尼亞語的知識。如果閣下希望在這兩種語言得到幫助，本人也可以提供幫助。
本人聯絡電話:xxx
本人聯絡電郵:xxx

Answer (score 0):

My attempt (although it's probably 1 year too late):

> 聘用廣東話教師
>
> 本人欲學習廣東話，故需一位教師。
>
> 如閣下能說廣東話，亦樂意教學的話，敬請聯絡本人。
>
> 本人願付學費，亦希望教師能說基本的英語或羅馬尼亞語。
>
> 如閣下有意在這兩種語言得到幫助，本人亦當盡力幫助。
>
> 聯絡電話：xxx...
>
> 聯絡電郵：xxx...

Comment: I would also like to replace one of the "幫助"s with another word...